# Error in a python program, maybe vtk related. Help please?

Tags: python, vtk

I am very very new to python, I am running this program and it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: In /builddir/build/BUILD/VTK6.0.0/Common/ExecutionModel/vtkDemandDrivenPipeline.cxx, line 715
vtkCompositeDataPipeline (0x2987f40): Input port 0 of algorithm vtkXMLStructuredGridWriter(0x2985d30) has 0 connections but is not optional.
```

Here is the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bvts.py", line 65, in <module>
    writer.SetInput(grid)
AttributeError: SetInput
```

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Here is the program. Thanks in advance :)

```
import vtk
import math

nx = 4
ny = 4
nz = 40

def ijk_to_xyz(i,j,k):
  z = 2*3.14159*k/(nz - 1.0)
  x = math.sin(z) + (-1.0 + 2.0*i/(nx - 1.0))
  y = -1.0 + 2.0*j/(ny - 1.0)
  return (x,y,z)

def ijk_to_index(i,j,k):
  return i*(ny*nz) + j*nz + k

grid = vtk.vtkStructuredGrid()
grid.SetDimensions(40,4,4)

pts = vtk.vtkPoints()
pts.SetNumberOfPoints(nx*ny*nz)

p = 0
for i in range(nx):
  for j in range(ny):
     for k in range(nz):
    x,y,z = ijk_to_xyz(i,j,k)
    pts.InsertPoint(p, x, y, z)
        p = p + 1

grid.SetPoints(pts)

cdata = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
cdata.SetNumberOfComponents(1)
cdata.SetNumberOfTuples((nx-1)*(ny-1)*(nz-1))
cdata.SetName('cellData')

p = 0
for i in range(nx-1):
  for j in range(ny-1):
    for k in range(nz-1):
      cdata.InsertValue(p, i+j+k)
      p = p + 1

grid.GetCellData().SetScalars(cdata)

pdata = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
pdata.SetNumberOfComponents(1)
pdata.SetNumberOfTuples(nx*ny*nz)
pdata.SetName('pointData')

p = 0
for i in range(nx):
  for j in range(ny):
    for k in range(nz):
      pdata.InsertValue(p, i+j+k)
      p = p + 1

grid.GetPointData().SetScalars(pdata)

writer = vtk.vtkXMLStructuredGridWriter()
writer.SetFileName('grid.vts')
writer.SetInput(grid)
writer.Update()
```

Comment: The code is compiling and producing a proper result on my end. Please post your full traceback.

Comment: @Nanashi I am not sure what it is (I have not really written any program in Python, I am studying this one for a project I am supposed to do), but is this what you asked?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bvts.py", line 65, in <module>
    writer.SetInput(grid)
AttributeError: SetInput

Comment: Yes, kindly edit your OP and post it there for better readability and documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Can you kindly tell me what your Python and `vtk` versions are? For Python, simply type `python` in your command line (I believe you're using a UNIX type machine) and tell me the number that shows up after that. For `vtk`, please type `import vtk`, press return, then `print vtk.__version__`. Alternatively, if that errors out, go back to your command line (not inside Python) and enter `pip freeze`. Look for `VTK==x.x.x`. Mine, for example, is `VTK=5.10.1`.

Comment: Python is `Python 2.7.5` , and for `VTK` I couldn't get it inside Python, and when I tried to use pip freeze, it didn't find the command. But I assume it's `VTK6.0.0`, since in the error the path contains `VTK6.0.0` folder

Comment: Can you try uninstalling `VTK` and reinstalling it via `pip install vtk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SetInput method is replaced on VTK6 see http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Replacement_of_SetInput

You should try this instead of SetInput:

```
writer->SetInputConnection(grid->GetProducerPort());
```

Comment: Thank you, this specific line didn't work, but the link was very helpful. I found the line that fixed it!